# uninstall numpy1.6.1 and install numpy1.5.1 instead on linux and [it's about to use GIPSY-OASIS II version6]

Tags: python, linux, numpy, uninstallation

I'm going to try the software GIPSY-OASIS II version6, so I had installed numpy-1.6.1 on Python 2.7.3 on Linux and when I tried to verify it (written by my advisor and succeed to run before) [I'm the beginner on both linux and python.]

Numpy 1.6.1 is installed, but GIPSY was built with Numpy 1.5.1. Some verify tests will fail.

```
AND THEN,
Preparing to run utility tests
  PASSED   - test of the env => xyz program
  PASSED   - test of pr2p
  PASSED   - test of the gps <=> prn programs
  PASSED   - test of qm programs
**FAILED** - test of some read programs & eci & jpl 
             Check log file in utility/run for details
  PASSED   - test of the rnx <=> crx programs
  PASSED   - test of stacov-related programs
  PASSED   - test of tdp programs
  PASSED   - test of the GIPSY time programs
  PASSED   - test of the tp_nml program

  Elapsed time: 27.4 seconds
```

I think the problem came from numpy 1.6.1, I thought I'd rather uninstall / remove  numpy 1.6.1 before installing another numpy version which seemed to work better to solve the kind of problem.

It means I want to install 1.5.1 instead and now I have download it as python-numpy.tar.gz (by the way I do not know how uninstall numpy 1.6.1 or remove it or how to replace it with the version of 1.5.1 that I've downloaded). All I found after seeing the problem is none of solutions and I might not have searched enough.

Thanks much if you would be kind to find the way out for this.

Comment: How do you know it's because of `numpy`? What does the log file say? What tests fail and what is the stack trace?

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to set up a virtual environment (with [virtualenv](http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/)) to install the older version of numpy. Even if you absolutely have to install numpy at a system level, you can at least test the build in the virtual environment first. After you get that working, just use the old version from within the virtual environment when you need it. If you absolutely have to install the older version of numpy at the system level, then after you determine that it works in the virtual environment, you can install it under `/usr/local`. But try to avoid uninstalling software that was installed at the system level to replace it with an older version because that is inviting dependency problems.

After installing virtualenv, create and activate a virtual environment:

```
$ virtualenv foo
New python executable in foo/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip...done.
$ . foo/bin/activate
(foo) $
```

Then you can tell `pip` which version of numpy you would like to install (no need to download it yourself):

```
(foo) $ pip install numpy==1.5.1
```

Comment: Thank you much for your kindness and sorry that I have to ask you how to install the old numpy 1.5.1 under /usr/local ??? ,I'm just the beginner on linux also python. It's just I'm still learning on them now. :) Thank you again ! :D

Comment: If you are going to build numpy from the command line, you can specify the install directory with an argument when you run `./configure`. If you are the only user who needs it and you don't want it in a virtual environment, you could also install it under your user directory with `pip install --user numpy==1.5.1`.

Comment: But the very first I thought I have to install any other things. I found no match with sudo and pip.[As I said I just start to use it so I actually don't understand what command tried to tell me, I would google it to find what's it too.] Anyway, Thank you for your kindness I'm so impressed :D:D                                           cusv@cusv-HP-EliteBook-8460p#/home/cusv> [sudo] pip install virtualenv
[sudo]: No match.
cusv@cusv-HP-EliteBook-8460p#/home/cusv>sudo pip install virtualenv
[sudo] password for cusv: 
sudo: pip: command not found

Comment: Looks like you are missing pip so `sudo apt-get install python-pip`.

Comment: to install `sudo apt-get install python-pip` I've done this but I don't know what version of pip I've installed because I want to install recommend version of the virtualenv as the link you give me. Thank you so much much much that help me a lot. I'm not good at programming and I have to make my project done soon.

Comment: At first I've tired `$ curl -O https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/v/virtualenv/virtualenv-X.X.tar.gz
$ tar xvfz virtualenv-X.X.tar.gz
$ cd virtualenv-X.X
$ [sudo] python setup.py install` but I got failed on `curl` command not found,then, I tried `$ [sudo] pip install virtualenv `

Comment: but after that I found that `SSLError: The read operation timed out.` So, I don't know what happened.

Comment: The version of pip shouldn't matter. If it installed, it should be fine and it will install the latest available version of virtualenv, which is what you want.